# DXL to truncate Object number

Tags: ibm-doors

I inherited some DXL code to truncate the Object Number to exclude the last “0”
This works fine for paragraphs numbers less than 10 (or a double digit number). I’ll admit to be new to DXL, but this code stumps me as I am not familiar with RegExp. I know that those on this forum will look at this and get the answer  and I will then learn and move forward.
Here is the code:

```
string s = number(obj)
Regexp paraNumExp = regexp2 "[0-9](\\.[0-9])*"
if(paraNumExp s)  obj.attrDXLName =  s[match 0]
delete paraNumExp
```

This is what is produces:
[AbsNum, ObjNumber, DXL Attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhVYV.png)

Here is the DXL code for the attached file (output from the test module)
(DXL) Paragraph Number 1

```
string s = number(obj)
Regexp paraNumExp = regexp2 "[1-9](\\.[1-9])*"
if(paraNumExp s)  obj.attrDXLName =  s[match 0]
delete paraNumExp
```

(DXL) Paragraph Number 2

```
string s = number(obj)
Regexp paraNumExp = regexp2 "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"
if(paraNumExp s)  obj.attrDXLName =  s[match 0]
delete paraNumExp
```

(DXL) Paragraph Number 4

```
Regexp reZero = regexp2 "(\\.0)-"
string s = number(obj)
if (reZero s) {
        obj.attrDXLName = s[0:start 1-1]
}
delete reZero
```

[DOORS output with what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBRLZ.png)

Comment: As you can see, this works fine until 4.10, 4.11, 4.12...

Comment: I am not familiar with DXL, but is the first part a string-to-number-to-string conversion? That alone is quite fishy. I would recommend just taking the obj as a string and using a regexp like `regexp2 "^[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+"`. Your current pattern with `(\\.[0-9])*` has the grouping in the wrong spot -- you want to group the numbers, not `.` followed by a number.

Comment: The method you suggested was not successful. I worked for 1.14, whereas for 1.14.14 it resulted in 1.14

Comment: Hey Gary! Could you add a column to that image that has what you expect to see? Would be helpful in addressing this. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my issue and included a screen shot of what I have and what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Not super sure, what you are trying to accomplish, or what is the deeper problem here. But to answer your question for "truncating the pending zeros", I would suggest to use "start" and "end" methods here, e.g.:

```
Regexp reZero = regexp2 "(\\.0)-"

Module m = current
filtering off
Object o
for o in m do {

    string strON = number( o )
    
    string strTruncated = strON
    if (reZero strON) {
        strTruncated = strON[0:start 1-1] "" strON[end 1+1:]
    }
    
    print "" identifier( o ) ": " strON " => '" strTruncated "'\n"
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your DXL code in a DXL Attribute, but it STOPS DOORS. It does execute in the Edit DXL window, but I need this as a DXL Attribute. To be more clear, for an Object number of 1.14.12.4.0-1 I need to output 1.14.12.4

Comment: My code is for use in the DXL console. In a DXL attribute, you don't need to iterate over all objects in a module. That's, what the dxl attribute already does for you. So, remove the loop, and to give the result back (as a String or Text), use "o.attrDXLName = ", instead of using the print method, as this is also is used for console output.

Comment: Updated DXL "Regexp reZero = regexp2 "(\\.0)-"
string s = number(obj)
if (reZero s) {
        obj.attrDXLName = s[0:start 1-1]
}
delete reZero"

Comment: But now the whole numbers do not appear: 4.10 results in blank, whereas 4.10.0-0 yields (correctly) 4.10

Answer (score 0):

With your help and a little bugging of a colleague, I got the results I need.
This is the DXL code:

```
// Define reZero to detect ".0-"
Regexp reZero = regexp2 "(\\.0)-"
// Get the Object Number
string s = number(obj)
if (reZero s) {
  // Found ".0-"? Strip off ".0-" and all following that string
  obj.attrDXLName = s[0:start 1-1]
} else {
  // Did not find ".0-". Use complete object number.
  obj.attrDXLName = s
}
delete reZero
```